# PageUp/PageDown -- how to catch properly?

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, kernel, macos

I am [here](https://viewsourcecode.org/snaptoken/kilo/03.rawInputAndOutput.html#the-page-up-and-page-down-keys) on a tutorial to build a text editor.

I'm finding that on my macOS (it works on a Linux VM), even with raw mode enabled, I'm unable to intercept `Page Up` and `Page Down`, which are sent via `fn-<arrow up>` `fn-<arrow down>`. How can I intercept these correctly?

Here's a simple program that you can use to see this (you can also use `od -tx1`, following with `C-d`):

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct termios orig_termios;

void
disable_raw_mode (void)
{
  tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &orig_termios);
}

void
enable_raw_mode (void)
{
  tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &orig_termios);
  atexit(disable_raw_mode);

  struct termios raw = orig_termios;
  raw.c_iflag &= ~(BRKINT | INPCK | PARMRK | INLCR | IGNCR | ISTRIP | ICRNL | IXON);
  raw.c_oflag &= ~(OPOST);
  raw.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ICANON | IEXTEN | ISIG);
  raw.c_cflag &= ~(CSIZE | PARENB);
  raw.c_cflag |= (CS8);


  tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &raw);
}

int
main (void)
{
  enable_raw_mode();
  
  char c;
  while ( read(STDIN_FILENO,  &c, 1) == 1 && c != 'q')
    {
      if (iscntrl(c))
        printf("%d\n", c);
      else
        printf("%d ('%c')\n", c, c);
    }

  return 0;
}
```

I want the final text editor to work on all POSIX-compliant systems that support escape sequences via the terminal.

Note that both `emacs` and `vim` are able to catch these keystrokes, so I know it is possible.